# Prolog пересечение двух списков

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, visual-prolog

Задание: Даны два списка.Занести элементы из первого списка в результирующий, если он однократно содержится во втором. Если элемент отсутствует во втором списке или содержится два или более раз, то в результирующий список этот элемент не попадает

Суть вопроса: как сделать так, чтобы в результирующий список не заносились элементы из первого списка, которые содержатся во втором 2 и более раз?

Программа:

```
DOMAINS
list=integer*

PREDICATES
nondeterm includes(list, integer)
nondeterm result(list, list, list)


CLAUSES
includes([A|_],A).
includes([_|TAIL],A1):-includes(TAIL,A1).

result([],_,[]).
result([Head|Tail],List,[Head|NewTail]):- includes(List,Head),result(Tail,List,NewTail),!.
result([_|Tail],List,NewTail):-result(Tail,List,NewTail).
GOAL
First=[1,2,3,4,5,6], Second=[1,1,1,2,3,4,4,6], result(First,Second,Result).
```

Результат работы такой:
First=[1,2,3,4,5,6], Second=[1,1,1,2,3,4,4,6], Result=[1,2,3,4,6]

А нужно, чтобы был такой:
First=[1,2,3,4,5,6], Second=[1,1,1,2,3,4,4,6], Result=[2,3,6]

Answer (score 1):

> Суть вопроса: как сделать так, чтобы в результирующий список не заносились элементы из первого списка, которые содержатся во втором 2 и более раз?

Просто поставьте **determ** для `includes/2`.